# Let the probability generating function, $G_X(t)$ of a discrete random variable be $G_X(t) = 2+t (2−t^2)(4−t) .$ Find $P(X = 3).$

Tags: probability

Let the probability generating function, $G_X(t)$ of a discrete random variable be given by
$$G_X(t) = 2+t
(2−t
^2)(4−t).$$
Find $P(X = 3).$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Could you edit your post to include what you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I've edited. I assume `t2` should be $t^2$ and `Gx` should be $G_x.$

Comment: This can't be a probability generating function, because some of the coefficients are $>1$ and some of them are negative.

Comment: Maybe it is meant to be $$\frac{2+t}{(2-t^2)(4-t)}?$$ or something similar?

Comment: I figured that guess because $G_x(1)$ must be equal to $1,$ and in general, minus signs need to occur in the denominators of the function.